# Force mouse pointer to show on touchscreen Windows 8 device

Tags: windows-8, mouse, vnc, touchscreen

I am trying to use VNC to control a Windows 8 tablet. Because the device does not have a mouse, it will not show a pointer, even when I'm connecting to it with VNC.

The specific VNC client I'm using is [HippoRemote](http://hipporemote.com) on the iPhone which emulates a mouse pad.

Is it possible to force Windows to show the pointer even though no mouse is installed? Preferably only when VNC is being used, but other solutions are also welcome.

Answer (score 4):

One workaround is to turn on [mouse keys](http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/windows8/use-numeric-keypad.aspx), that seems to show the mouse when the mouse is moved (via VNC) and hide it when the touchscreen is touched.

One downside with this is that the numeric keyboard (if available) won't be usable.